# Why are repeating groups required when requesting market data over FIX?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

Can anyone tell me, why we need to use repeating groups in market data request. And what response/reply should we receive from acceptor against market data request. Please tell how can we receive market data request on acceptor side?

**Sending Market Data request**

```
public void sendMarketDataRequest(SessionID sessionId, String request, int ord){ // request new or old
        String bankName = "HBL";
        String mdReqCcyPair = "EURUSD";
        String mkdreqId = "010qwerty";

        SubscriptionRequestType type = new SubscriptionRequestType('1');
        if(request.equals("new")){
            reqId.put(mkdreqId, mkdreqId);
        }else{
            type.setValue('2');
        }

        quickfix.fix44.MarketDataRequest mdRequest = new quickfix.fix44.MarketDataRequest(new MDReqID(mkdreqId), type, new MarketDepth(1));
        mdRequest.setField(new quickfix.field.Symbol(mdReqCcyPair));
        mdRequest.setField(new Product(2));
        mdRequest.setField(new NoRelatedSym(1));
        mdRequest.setField(new MDUpdateType(0));
        mdRequest.setField(new NoMDEntryTypes(3));
        mdRequest.setField(new StringField(582, "1"));

        quickfix.fix44.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh.NoMDEntries group = new quickfix.fix44.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh.NoMDEntries();
            group.set(new MDEntryType('0'));
            group.set(new MDEntryPx(12.32));
            group.set(new MDEntrySize(10));
            group.set(new OrderID("OrderId"));
            mdRequest.addGroup(group);

            group.set(new MDEntryType('1'));
            group.set(new MDEntryPx(12.32));
            group.set(new MDEntrySize(10));
            group.set(new OrderID("OrderId"));
            mdRequest.addGroup(group);

        qCcyPair.substring(0, 3);
        mdRequest.setField(new Currency(mdReqDealtCcy));
        mdRequest.setField(new NoPartyIDs(1));
        mdRequest.setField(new PartyID(bankName));

        try{
            boolean re = Session.sendToTarget(mdRequest, sessionId);
            System.out.println(mdRequest);
            System.out.println(re);
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

**Receiving End Code**

```
public void onMessage( quickfix.fix44.MarketDataRequest message,  SessionID sessionID )
                  throws FieldNotFound, UnsupportedMessageType, IncorrectTagValue {

                  System.out.println("On Message:   "+message);
}
```

Comment: Erm, what's the context?  Who says you need to use repeating groups in market data requests, and what requests are these you're talking about?

Comment: he is talking about FIX repeating groups I'm just going through the reasoning and will get back to him once my coffee has reached my brain

Comment: Removed `java` tag since this does not necessarily have anything to do with Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Market data requests are not normally used for a single instrument; you normally want market data for a set of instruments. Each group in the repeating group set represents an instrument you want data for. The response will depend on your counterparty and when you last had a full market data refresh (usually daily). On your initial request and then at a fixed schedule thereafter you will receive a full market data refresh message . If your counterparty supports an intraday update model you will then receive snapshot refresh messages which are partial data refreshes. The snapshot message provides an update on just the market data that has changed since last refresh (full or partial) and is intended to be a smaller message and therefore, hopefully, lower latency. Not all counterparties support partial refresh. If you are on the acceptor side where you are receiving market data requests (obviously normally on the sell side) you should provide a full market data refresh first covering all of the requested instrument details. Whether you support incremental updates is a business decision.

Comment: can you please tell how can i receive/read mkd request on acceptor side.

Comment: Here is my code. 
` public void onMessage( quickfix.fix44.MarketDataIncrementalRefresh message,  SessionID sessionID )
            throws FieldNotFound, UnsupportedMessageType, IncorrectTagValue {
        
          System.out.println("On Message: "+message);
     }  
 `

Comment: youre using the wrong OnMessage function - if you are receiving a Market data request you need to use that OnMessage overlaod

Comment: i overloaded that function too. but still no effect. i am adding code in my question.

Comment: Does it connect, heartbeat and send the message successfully? I will assume that you're sending the correct versioned message

Comment: yes it is connected and exchange heartbeat as well. I also send NewsingleOrder, that was received by acceptor. but when i try to send MarketDataRequest. not receiving by Acceptor

Comment: are you getting any reject messages? look for them in the logs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15372/discussion-between-muneeb-and-md-tech)

Comment: sorry, am a bit snowed under. Try the examples on the quickfixj website. I'm guessing that you're not populating a required tag or don't have a data dictionary configured.

Comment: No problem. n thanks for your cooperation. I fix the problem. Some tags are not defined that why message was rejected. i removed that tags now it working fine. Thanks :)